# Composer telling me " PHP extension ext-gmp * but it is missing" when it shouldn't be

Tags: php7, composer

I'm new to Composer, so be gentle!

I'm trying to install a script that uses Composer, but I get:

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-gmp * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.
```

After researching, I've found you have to install GMP, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gmp
```

That installed fine. Then I both:

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
```

..and added in:

```
extension=gmp.so
```

Yet when I run the script again, I still get that error message!

From the frontend with `<? ech phpinfo() ?>` I get it fine: (but I'm aware CLI and front-end PHP-FPM stuff runs under different configs);

[image]

What am I missing? Its driving me nuts! I'm also getting errors about
the PHP version:

Comment: do you have multiple PHP versions installed on the system? Is it possible that your `composer` is using a different version other than `php-7.4`?

Comment: Thanks - that was it! I found this command: `composer config platform.php 7.4`, and now the message has gone away :) I guess it was trying to use the latest version of PHP (we have 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.5, 8.0 and 8.1!)